# Prove that the polynomial $f(x)= x^4 + 2x^2 + 2x + 1998$ cannot be writen as the product of two quadratic polynomials with integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Assume that $f(x)=p(x)q(x)$ with  $p(x),~q(x)$ quadratics over $\mathbb{Z}$. Comparing coefficients of $x^4$, the leading coefficients of $p$ and $q$ are both equal to $+1$ or $-1$. In the second case, one can replace the quadratics by their negatives. Then one can write

$$p(x)=x^2+ax+b, \quad q(x)=x^2+cx+d,$$

with $a,~b,~c,~d\in\mathbb{Z}$. Doing the calculations and comparing coefficients gives
the nonlinear system

$$a+c=0,\quad ac+b+d=2,\quad ad+bc=2,\quad bd=1998.$$

From the first equation, $c=-a$. Replacing $c=-a$ into the second one gives $d=a^2-b+2$. Replacing $c=-a$ and $d=a^2-b+2$ into the third equation gives

$$a(a^2-2b+2)=2$$

I am puzzled how to use this equation and the last one of the system, $bd=1998$, to get a contradiction. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You have $ak=2$ over $\Bbb Z$. So what can $a$ be? How many divisors does $2$ have?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Thanks. 1 and 2. If $a=2$, then the factor $a^2-2b+2$ is even. So 2 has been factored as the product of two even numbers; contradiction.

Comment: @DietrichBurde For $a=1$, I get also a contradiction $3-2b=2\Rightarrow b=1/2$. Should I check the other divisors $-1$ and $-2$? Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @radekzak Thank you very much for the link. I see that there are also relevant questions in MSE. I hold a physics diploma and and a PhD in Applied Mechanics. I teach primarily Engineering Mathematics but in my spare time I try to study on my own abstract algebra, analysis, etc.

Comment: And similarly for $a=-1$ and $a=-2.$

Comment: Replacing $c$ with $-a$ in the third equation gives $ad+bc=2 \implies a(d-b)=2$.  So $d-b$ is a factor of $2$; i.e., $|d-b| \le 2$.  But it's impossible for two integers that close together to have $1998$ as their product.

Comment: I just want to comment that a problem like this can be solved without any clever tricks or special insight. There aren't that many possibilities for $b$ and $d$ such that $bd = 1998$ over the integers. Try each case (actually only $b < d$ WLOG). You know $a = -c$, so the second equation means you only have to check that $b + d - 2$ is not a perfect square in each case

Comment: I don't mean to say that this problem is easy. Just that you shouldn't be afraid to go for stupid solutions if a clever solution is not forthcoming. In this case, the problem readily yields to the stupid approach of just checking factors of $1998$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only $a+c=o, ad+bc=2\Leftrightarrow a(d-b)=2\Rightarrow d=b\pm1, \pm2$ while bd=1998. Then try to solve the resulting quadratic in b.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way: use a calculator like Wolfram Alpha to compute the four roots, then check every possible product $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots.